# ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Tags: python, pyodbc, sqlparameter

When running the below script it ends in the following error, as I do find other posts on this error I am not finding the fix similar to my script.  Thanks for the help!

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DVO\Bo\Marketing Hours\archive\active_assets.py", line 9, in <module>
    r"D:\User folders\VOD_Titles\BCST_assets.txt"
  File "D:\DVO\Bo\Marketing Hours\archive\seac_assets.py", line 67, in main
    assets = [asset_record(*row) for results in mssql_query(connect_string, sql_string, [today_string, today_string]) for row in results]
  File "D:\DVO\Bo\Marketing Hours\archive\seac_assets.py", line 67, in <listcomp>
    assets = [asset_record(*row) for results in mssql_query(connect_string, sql_string, [today_string, today_string]) for row in results]
  File "D:\DVO\Bo\Marketing Hours\archive\seac_assets.py", line 24, in mssql_query
    db_cursor.execute(sql_string, vars)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')*
```

**This is the main script, calling on seac_assets**

```
import seac_assets

if __name__ == "__main__":
  online = True

  if online:
    seac_assets.main(
      "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=172.18.192.68;DATABASE=IdwData;UID=suddenlink;PWD=5udd3nlink",
      r"D:\User folders\VOD_Titles\BCST_assets.txt"
    )
    seac_assets.main(
      "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=172.19.241.51;DATABASE=IdwData;UID=suddenlink;PWD=5udd3nlink",
      r"D:\User folders\VOD_Titles\CHRM_assets.txt"
    )
```

**This is the actual code using pyodbc which ends in error**

```
import pyodbc
import csv
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

asset_record = namedtuple("asset_record", """\
wuid,
name,
title_brief,
activate_date,
deactivate_date""")

def mssql_query(connect_string,
                sql_string,
                vars=None,
                TIMEOUT_VALUE=300,
                FETCH_ROWS=5000,
                MAX_ROWS=10 ** 6):
  # Set up the database connection and cursor
  db_conn = pyodbc.connect(connect_string, timeout=TIMEOUT_VALUE)
  db_cursor = db_conn.cursor()

  # Execute the passed SQL statements
  db_cursor.execute(sql_string, vars)

  r = [] # Holds one batch of results
  L = 0
  while True:
    r = db_cursor.fetchmany(FETCH_ROWS)
    if r == []: # fetchmany() returns [] when finished
      break
    L += len(r)
    if L > MAX_ROWS:
      print(">>Fetched more than ", MAX_ROWS, ", aborting.")
      break
    yield r
    print("Fetched {} rows".format(L))
  print(">>Finished fetching rows.")

  #End the database connection and return the results
  db_cursor.close()
  db_conn.close()

def main(connect_string, outfile_path):
  sql_string = """\
SELECT
  ref.WUID,
  ref.Name,
  a.TitleBrief,
  dates.ActivateDate,
  dates.DeactivateDate
FROM
  dbo.WHIDS_Asset AS ref WITH (NOLOCK)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.WHIDS_ATitleBrief AS a WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON ref.WUID = a.WUID
  LEFT JOIN dbo.WHIDS_AActivateDeactivateDates AS dates WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON ref.WUID = dates.WUID
WHERE
  dates.DeactivateDate >= ?
  AND a.TitleBrief IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
  dates.DeactivateDate"""

  today = datetime.today()
  today_string = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  print (asset_record)
  assets = [asset_record(*row) for results in mssql_query(connect_string, sql_string, [today_string, today_string]) for row in results]
  print (assets)

  with open(outfile_path, "w") as outfile:
    print("WUID",
          "NAME",
          "TITLE_BRIEF",
          "ACTIVATE_DATE",
          "DEACTIVATE_DATE",
          sep='\t',
          file=outfile)
    for a in assets:
      print(a.wuid,
            a.name,
            a.title_brief,
            a.activate_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
            a.deactivate_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
            sep='\t',
            file=outfile)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the error says you have one parameter marker and two parameters.  I look at your sql:

```
SELECT
  ref.WUID,
  ref.Name,
  a.TitleBrief,
  dates.ActivateDate,
  dates.DeactivateDate
FROM
  dbo.WHIDS_Asset AS ref WITH (NOLOCK)
  LEFT JOIN dbo.WHIDS_ATitleBrief AS a WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON ref.WUID = a.WUID
  LEFT JOIN dbo.WHIDS_AActivateDeactivateDates AS dates WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON ref.WUID = dates.WUID
WHERE
  dates.DeactivateDate >= ?
  AND a.TitleBrief IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
  dates.DeactivateDate
```

I see one parameter marker (the `?` in your where clause).

When I look at the place where you submit the query:

```
mssql_query(connect_string, sql_string, [today_string, today_string])
```

I see you passing two copies of `today_string` as parameters.  Just like the error message said: one parameter marker, two parameters.  Try changing the query to

```
mssql_query(connect_string, sql_string, [today_string])
```

Comment: Also, I'm not super familiar with `pyodbc` you probably don't need to convert the date to a string.  It should be able to handle a datetime object directly.

Comment: In this case, the datetime conversion to string is also serving the purpose of stripping off time due to specified `%Y-%m-%d` format. However, you are correct that string conversion for the date isn't required -- pyodbc will happily take a python date object. `today = datetime.now().date()`

Comment: Thanks jcdyer, seems like I missed an easy one.